# How convert an .xlsx to Google Sheets format

Tags: python, spreadsheet

I am trying to convert an Excel file like `Excel.xlsx` to Google-Sheets.

I tried to read it like a normal spreadsheet but it didn't work, see error below

```
import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import pandas as pd
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)


woorkbook = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19vWu-OSjAKSvfh8FgvZClk4aGsGxx5ej/edit#gid=198588977')
sheet = woorkbook.get_worksheet(0)
list_of_lists = sheet.get_all_values()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'This operation is not supported for this document', 'status': 'FAILED_PRECONDITION'}
 
How can I do that?
```

Comment: What is `gc`? What is returned by `gc.open_by_url()`, and why do you expect it to have a method named `get_all_values`? Did you find that in some documentation? Can you provide a link?

Comment: When posting Python code on SO, we usually include the `import` statements (as required by [example]). Consult [ask] and do research (like in the docs of your library) first. If still something is unclear add a link to the docs.

Comment: I tried to do what @hc_dev mention but its not working... i thing its because the format of the file is xlxs.    APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'This operation is not supported for this document', 'status': 'FAILED_PRECONDITION'}

Comment: How did you get you Excel-file to Google, did you upload to Google Drive and then use "Open with Google Sheets" (e.g. in Chrome) to open it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention the library you use and reference with `gc`.

Assume you are using

> [*gspread*](https://pypi.org/project/gspread/), a Python API for Google Sheets that uses Google Sheets API v4.

Then read the docs:

1. `woorkbook = gc.open_by_url( url )` [opens a spreadsheet](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet) or **workbook** (a workbook contains sheets)
2. `sheet = woorkbook.get_worksheet(0)` [gets the first sheet](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet) of a spreadsheet or workbook
3. `list_of_lists = sheet.get_all_values()` [reads all values](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-lists) of this sheet